# How to transform CoAP to HTTP?

Tags: python, http, coap

I searched but did not found any example showing on how to convert CoAP request or response to HTTP request.

Basically what I want to do is CoAP request POST some data from device to a server which will translate it and do HTTP request POST to other server to be save inside the database.

While the part to save the data is not a major problem right now, I did not managed to find any example script showing how to convert from CoAP to HTTP.

I already looked at [coapthon](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon) , [aiocoap](https://github.com/chrysn/aiocoap) but since aiocoap requires python 3.5,(I use python 2.7) that left me with coapthon. Unfortunately coapthon only has HTTP to CoAP proxy while CoAP to HTTP is still in development.

If anyone know other project regarding this or has any opinion on how to solve this, I am glad if you can share it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is called Protocol **Interoperability**. You Need a `CoAP - HTTP` and `HTTP - CoAP` proxy that can translate the messages between them.

Here is [californium-proxy](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/californium-proxy) on GitHub, I am using it already. Here is the [example](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/demo-apps/cf-proxy) that shows how to use it.